# How to find the array size?

Tags: c++

Here is my simple code in c++..

```
int getSize(int *array){
int n = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
return n;
```

}

```
int main(){
    int array[4] ={1,2,3,4};
    std::cout<< getSize(array)<<std::endl; // prints 2 (first 2 elements)
}
```

I am a newbie in C++. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: sizeof(array) returns the size of a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::size_t getSize(const int (&)[N]){ return N; }
```

Comment: From the OP: "I am a newbie in C++." I.e. doesn't know templates or lambdas. If you're going to use advanced techniques, at least explain them to some degree.